# Get the sum of the numbers generated by sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named `Company` which has categorized by several `sector_id`

`SELECT sector_id,count(sector_id) FROM Company group by sector_id`

I could get the company numbers like this

```
sector_id count(sector_id)
1         10
2         15
3         22
```

Then, I would like to get the sum of count(sector_id) `10 + 15 + 22`

Is it possible to do this by sql only? or I need to make some code with php??

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag appropriately.

Comment: @asdhblinkenight some company has null as sector_id. So, it is not equal

Comment: @Gordom Linoff I am using mysql so I updated the tag

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `group by`:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM Company ;
```

EDIT:

It occurs to me that you want a summary row *as well as* the original data.  If so, you can use `rollup` or `grouping sets` in most databases.  Something like this:

```
SELECT sector_id, count(sector_id)
FROM Company 
GROUP BY sector_id WITH ROLLUP;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to calculate sum using `sql` by using `SUM()` method

*Syntax :*

```
SELECT SUM(column_name)
FROM Table_Name;
```

*In your case it will be like this :*

```
SELECT SUM(sector_id)
FROM Company ;
```

Hope it helps.